# angularjs - POST an array of objects(JSON data) to a PHP page

Tags: php, json, angularjs

An example of how my JSON data is like:

```
$scope.a = [{
            "email": "keval@gmail",
            "permissions": {
                "upload": "1",
                "edit": "1"
            }
        }, {
            "email": "new@aa",
            "permissions": {
                "upload": "1",
                "edit": "1"
            }
        }];
```

I want to post the same, and here's my approach:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'backend/savePermissions.php',
    data: {
        mydata: $scope.a
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And the PHP is to take the request and respond:

```
echo $_POST['mydata'];
```

I tried `JSON.stringify` before the call and `json_decode` while echoing it back; still didn't work. Been trying all the possibilities I can think of, and what I find on the web/other questions, but still not working.

Comment: I think that if the value for the attribute in the data object is undefined, then   it is not even sent I tried to add null and could see it in the request headers at the console. http://plnkr.co/edit/IqQY5dJoS5VMObsYsbha?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt if I followed what you said. Anyway, I got a solution below. Thank you.

Comment: @keval are you trying to make webservice using AngularJS and PHP ? If yes then I want to know if your json output is parse the JSON validation in jsonlint.com or not, because I am trying to do the same (webservice in AngularJS + PHP) and I am getting whole html in JSONLint parsing

Comment: Yes, my JSON is valid as per JSONLint. And I am not getting you, what do you mean by "getting whole html"? Could you post your code in a new question and give me the link? Or just show me the code and I will try to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made plnkr for you
http://plnkr.co/edit/K8SFzQKfWLffa6Z4lseE?p=preview

```
$scope.postData = function () {
    $http.post('http://edeen.pl/stdin.php', {user:$scope.formData}).success(
      function(data){
        $scope.response = data
      })
  }
```

as you can see I'm sending a raw JSON without formating it, then in php

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I read the JSON directly and echo it but you can do whatever you want

read more about `php://input` here http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

I was using it for a long time for REST services to avoid transforming JSON to string to many times

Comment: Great! That one line is it, I'm getting the data in response; everything looks good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use this, with which I can send Array JSON:

```
var array = {}
array['key1'] = value1;
array['key2'] = value2;

$http.post(URL, array)
  .success(function(data){
  })
  .error(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using $httpParamSerializer or $httpParamSerializerJQLike

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'backend/savePermissions.php',
    data: $httpParamSerializer($scope.a),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```