# Post method to send array of data using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

This is my array where I store my pushed data,
now I want to send this data to server using http post method.

```
 $scope.workingSchedules = [{   
     workingDay: 'MONDAY',
     workingHours: [{ 
         fromTime: '1222' ,
         toTime: '1400'
     }]
 }];
```

This is my code to push data into array.

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
    $scope.workingSchedules.push({
         'workingDay':'MONDAY',
         'workingHours':[{
             'fromTime':$scope.fromTime,
             'toTime':$scope.toTime
         }]
    });
    $scope.fromTime='';
    $scope.toTime='';
    $scope.workingDay='';
};
```

How am I suppose to send this array using normal

```
 $http.post($scope.API_url,
    workingSchedules, config)
    .success(function(workingSchedules, status) {
```

Comment: Your data is supposed to be an object, so make it like this $http.post($scope.API_url, {data: workingSchedules}, config), Please check if the question already exists before posting, see comment below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851154/angularjs-post-an-array-of-objectsjson-data-to-a-php-page

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37965742/6449750 this too

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parts.
`Content-Type`, should be matched to your data.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

Or if you don't want to use `$httpProvider` :

```
$http.post($scope.API_url,workingSchedules, config, headers:{'Content-Type':"text/html"})
```

Look at [How to send post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data), for the right `format` of the `request`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering!! I have applied conf properly & my post, get ,put  works properly. I am having problem in sending the data i pushed into an array in UI and then sending that data back to server. Thanks